# Redirect to login page vs throwing 'Authorization Required' error page (Azure AD Graph MVC 5)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, owin, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I have a MVC 5 project that is structured similar to this sample code: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-web.

Whenever the Application Pool recycles, it throws an error 'Authorization Required' and displays the stack trace. This is where it executes within the code:

ProjectName/Utils/AuthenticationHelper.cs

```
namespace ProjectName.Utils
{
    internal class AuthenticationHelper
    {
        public static string token;

        /// <summary>
        ///     Async task to acquire token for Application.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Async Token for application.</returns>
        public static async Task<string> AcquireTokenAsync()
        {
            if (token == null || token.IsEmpty())
            {
                throw new Exception("Authorization Required.");
            }
            return token;
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Get Active Directory Client for Application.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>ActiveDirectoryClient for Application.</returns>
        public static ActiveDirectoryClient GetActiveDirectoryClient()
        {
            Uri baseServiceUri = new Uri(Constants.ResourceUrl);
            ActiveDirectoryClient activeDirectoryClient =
                new ActiveDirectoryClient(new Uri(baseServiceUri, Constants.TenantId),
                    async () => await AcquireTokenAsync());
            return activeDirectoryClient;
        }
    }
}
```

How do I redirect the user to the login page instead of `throw new Exception("Authorization Required.");` ?

Thank you for the help or insight in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `Exception` class is probably not a very good idea. You should make an exception class which says authorization is required, and then add a global exception filter which checks for this exception, and returns a 401 challenge instead of the error.

Something like:

```
public class AuthorizationRequiredExceptionFilter : IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.Exception is AuthorizationRequiredException)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Your authentication pipeline should respond to the 401 with a redirect to login if it is configured properly.

Adding the filter can be done in `FilterConfig`:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        filters.Add(new AuthorizationRequiredExceptionFilter());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I'm fairly new to this concept that you're suggesting. Is there additional resources you would recommend that may help me properly set this up in my application?

Comment: Just as a note to anyone that may find this useful, the project which uses this code does not have a custom 401 redirect URL (as configurable in the `Web.config`. We were informed by our cybersecurity team that it is not best practice (in our company) to have this as a method to handle exceptions.